Python Turtle - Exception has occurred: Terminator exception: no description
I am having trouble with running this code. I am trying to run an instance of turtle, successfully close it, and start a new instance of the turtle. I am able to complete the first iteration but I get a terminator exception raised: Exception has occurred: Terminator exception: no description at self.turt = Turtle(), when I debug the program.
I know self.screen.exitonclick() disposes the turtle and screen, but I thought I was creating a new instance of turtle and screen when I would call the class in Call_Turtle_Looping() below.
import numpy as np
from turtle import Turtle,Screen

class Turtle_Looping():
    def __init__(self):
        self.turt = Turtle()
        self.screen = Screen()
        self.angles = [20,45,65,80,90,95]
        self.colors = ["red","blue","red","black","red","blue"]
        
        
    
    def Basic_Move(self):
        
        for i in range(len(self.angles)):
            self.screen.tracer(0)
            self.turt.pendown()
            self.turt.color(self.colors[i])
            self.turt.right(self.angles[i])
            self.turt.forward(150)
            self.turt.penup()
            self.screen.update()

        self.screen.exitonclick()
        
def Call_Turtle_Looping():
    
    for i in range(4):       
        print(f"we are on run #{i}")
        inst = Turtle_Looping()
        inst.Basic_Move()
        
Call_Turtle_Looping()
               


Does this answer your question? Python Turtle.Terminator even after using exitonclick()

The following solution is a hack and is intended for use only in simple programs. It may not follow best practices and might lead to unexpected behavior in more complex or production-level code. Use it with caution.

When screen.exitonclick() is called, a Turtle module global variable _RUNNING is set to False. To fix this, we need to rearrange your __init__ function and set it to True:
from turtle import Turtle, Screen, TurtleScreen

class Turtle_Looping():
    def __init__(self):
        self.screen = Screen()
        TurtleScreen._RUNNING=True     #This has to happen before you call Turtle()
        self.turt = Turtle()

That's it!

Alternative: self.screen.onclick(lambda a,b: self.screen.reset())
Resets the Screen on click.

Turtle does not currently support closing a Screen and opening another. There is no other way. _destroy is the only way to close a Screen, and it always sets _RUNNING to false. Even calling bye() is just a wrapper for _destroy.

@ggorlen. To answer your question. I do need to destroy the screen and create a new instance from it. I believe I understand your point about sticking with the docs, and having well established programming paradigms. However, in this case, @SanguineL's answer has provided a solution. Prior to asking this question, I did experiment with bye(), but I was not achieving the desired results. As it would not restart the turtle drawing, when moving to the next iteration.

@ggorlen Regardless of best practices, the fact that _destroy does not return the program back to its starting state seems like a bug. I added a warning for your peace of mind.

@SanguineL Thanks. Feel free to open an issue with the CPython repo to fix it and feel free to clean up the comments here now that you've updated your answer.
